# Connecting to an external database with pgAdmin III

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, remote, tcpip

I'm trying to connect to an external database from pgAdmin III (which is installed on both machines).
The client complains:

> ## Access to database denied
>
> The server doesn't grant access to the database: the server reports
>
> ```
> FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.108.161",
>                                 user "postgres",
>                             database "postgres",
>                                  SSL off
> ```
>
> To access a database on a PostgreSQL server, you first have to grant primary access to the server for your client (Host Based Authentication).
>   PostgreSQL will check the `pg_hba.conf` file if a pattern that matches your client address / username / database is present and enabled before any `SQL GRANT` access control lists are evaluated.
>
> The initial settings in pg_hba.conf are quite restrictive, in order to avoid unwanted security holes caused by unreviewed but mandatory system settings.
>   You'll probably want to add something like
>
> ```
> host all all 192.168.0.0/24 md5
> ```
>
> This example grants MD5 encrypted password access to all databases to all users on the private network `192.168.0.0/24`.
>   You can use the `pg_hba.conf` editor that is built into pgAdmin III to edit the `pg_hba.conf` configuration file.
>
> After changing `pg_hba.conf`, you need to trigger a server configuration reload using `pg_ctl` or by stopping and restarting the server process.

Where the server explicitly states that *all* connections from the internal network are accepted.

`pg_hba.conf`

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             192.168.0.0/24          md5
```

I have already restarted the postmaster for the changes to take effect, and have gone so far as to restart the entire machine.
What else could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
 host    all             all             192.168.0.0/24          md5
```

will let through connections from IPs matching `192.168.0.X` where `X` is any byte.

The IP address of your error message being `192.168.108.161`, it does not match this pattern because `108` is not `0`.

To enable addresses like `192.168.X.Y`, you'd need a `/16` instead of `/24` meaning that the first 16 bits only are fixed.

Like this:

```
 host    all             all             192.168.0.0/16          md5
```

Don't forget to reload Postgresql. From the official docs, use `pg_ctl reload`. If that doesn't work, then there are other ways to do it listed in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/61383/reloading-postgresql-after-configuration-changes).

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get in today!  I didn't know the `/` was *how many bits were fixed* --- this makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: This was the problem, thanks for pointing it out!  Now, if I wanted to specify an *exact* IP address, would I use `192.168.108.161/32` or simply `192.168.108.161`?

Comment: This should be `192.168.108.161/32`. Also take the time to read the beginning of the `pg_hba.conf` file about the ADDRESS column, it's all explained.

Answer (score 2):

Two things come to mind.

1. The first is to make sure the server is listening on the network interface. By default it only listens on local host. Edit your `postgresql.conf` file and change:

   ```
   listen_addresses = 'localhost'
   ```

   To look like this instead:

   ```
   listen_addresses = '*'
   ```
2. If you're connecting remotely then your `postgres` user needs a password. By default there is no password associated with that account so only local trust based login works. For remote password login (eg. `md5` in pg_hba.conf`) to work either add a password or create a new user with a password.

Also, instead of using `host` in `pg_hba.conf` consider using `hostssl` to require that remote connections use SSL. Otherwise the username/password credentials are sent over the wire in plain text.

Comment: 1) I forgot to mention that I had edited `listen_addresses` thusly, but it will be helpful for future users to see that too.  2) When on the server, I can open up pgAdmin and then connect to the database.  It prompts me for a password, I put one in (our company has a standard password that we use for test stuff), and it connects.  Wouldn't it fail similarly if the `postgres` user had no password?

Comment: Try connecting from the command line via `psql` and see what error it reports. It should be verbose enough to figure out the cause. If it says `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user` then it's probably a mismatched password. If it says `could not connect to server: Connection refused` then it's probably a network/port issue. Is the CIDR you've specified of `192.168.0.0/24` correct? Should that be `192.168.1.0/24` (`1` instead of `0` for the third byte)?

Comment: `psql --host=192.168.108.160 --port=5433 --user=postgres postgres` fails with the same error (and no ability to make it more verbose): "FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host..."

Comment: I just checked the server, and it actually says something *very* interesting (considering this problem doesn't show up using pgAdmin): http://i.stack.imgur.com/g9aLK.png

Comment: Well one more point for `psql` then. How did pgAdmin connect locally then? I'm guessing you must have been connecting to a different database. Otherwise I can't see how a local connection would work either if the server won't startup.

Comment: It's possible.  I had had PostgreSQL 9.2 (command-line tools only) installed and was having issues installing pgAdmin.  We have a 9.1 binary with pgAdmin included so I ran that, and it may have installed its own `psql`.